# Reverse keys and values in dictionary if values are a list

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am trying to reverse the keys and values in the dictionary created by the values are lists. How can I approach this?
Here is the assignment:

Write Python program that will use the data from this file and create a dictionary with actor/actresses names as keys and the values being lists of movies with this actor/actress.  After creating a dictionary your program should ask user for actor/actress name and then, using the information in the dictionary, print the movies with this actor/actress.

```
in_file = open("movie and actors.txt", "r")

movie_dictionary = {}
for line in in_file:
    movies_and_actors = line.strip().split(', ')
    movie = movies_and_actors[0]
    actor = movies_and_actors[1:]
    movie_dictionary[movie] = actor

s = input("Enter an actor/actress name: ")
d = [i for i in movie_dictionary if s in movie_dictionary[i]]
listToStr = ' and '.join([elem for elem in d])
print("The movies that", s, "starred in are", listToStr)

in_file.close()
```

movies and actors.txt

```
La La Land, Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone
Blade Runner 2049, Harrison Ford, Ryan Gosling, Ana de Armas
Cruella, Emma Stone, Emma Thompson, Joel Fry
Iron Man, Robert Downey Jr., Gwyneth Paltrow, Terrence Howard
Avatar, Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver
Star Wars A New Hope, Mark Hamil, Carrie Fisher, Harrison Ford
Air Force One, Harrison Ford, Gary Oldman, Glen Close
Pretty Woman, Richard Gere, Julia Roberts, Jason Alexander
My Best Friend's Wedding, Julia Roberts, dermont Multroney, 
Cameron Diaz
There's Something About Mary, Cameron Diaz, Matt Dillon, Ben 
Stiller
Meet the Parents, Ben Stiller, Robert De Niro, Teri Polo
Top Gun Maverick, Tom Cruse, Jennifer Connelly, Miles Teller
Black Panther: Wakanda Forever, Letitia Wright, Lupita Nyong'o, 
Danai Gurira
Thor: Love and Thunder, Chris Hemsworth, Natalie Portman, 
Christian Bale
Notting Hill, Hugh Grant, Julia Roberts, Richard McCabe
```

Comment: your file is messed up, there's no separation between the last actor of a movie and the title of the next movie. Before coding you absolutely need to fix the file. Otherwise how do you expect to determine how to separate `Emma Stone Blade Runner 2049` without prior knowledge of the actor and movie films?

Comment: It should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not a data cleaning exercise and that your data is accurately represented by:

```py
rows = """
La La Land, Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone
Blade Runner 2049, Harrison Ford, Ryan Gosling, Ana de Armas
Cruella, Emma Stone, Emma Thompson, Joel Fry
Iron Man, Robert Downey Jr., Gwyneth Paltrow, Terrence Howard
Avatar, Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver
Star Wars A New Hope, Mark Hamil, Carrie Fisher, Harrison Ford
Air Force One, Harrison Ford, Gary Oldman, Glen Close
Pretty Woman, Richard Gere, Julia Roberts, Jason Alexander
My Best Friend's Wedding, Julia Roberts, dermont Multroney, Cameron Diaz
There's Something About Mary, Cameron Diaz, Matt Dillon, Ben Stiller
Meet the Parents, Ben Stiller, Robert De Niro, Teri Polo
Top Gun Maverick, Tom Cruse, Jennifer Connelly, Miles Teller
Black Panther: Wakanda Forever, Letitia Wright, Lupita Nyong'o, Danai Gurira
Thor: Love and Thunder, Chris Hemsworth, Natalie Portman, Christian Bale
Notting Hill, Hugh Grant, Julia Roberts, Richard McCabe
""".strip().split("\n")
```

Then you can process these rows one by one and capture the movie and list of actors. Then you can iterate over the list of actors and use the `setdefault()` method of a dictionary to ensure that new actor keys are properly initialized to an empty list to append into:

```py
appears_in = {}
for row in rows:
    movie, *actors = row.split(",")
    for actor in actors:
        appears_in.setdefault(actor.strip(), []).append(movie.strip())
```

Finally we can use the name of an actor to print their movies:

```
actor = "Harrison Ford"
print(f"{actor} has appeared in {', '.join(appears_in[actor])}")
```

The result should be:

```
Harrison Ford has appeared in Blade Runner 2049, Star Wars A New Hope, Air Force One
```

On the other hand, if this exercise invloves a data cleaning step becuase your data is actually as you stated:

```py
rows = """
La La Land, Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone
Blade Runner 2049, Harrison Ford, Ryan Gosling, Ana de Armas
Cruella, Emma Stone, Emma Thompson, Joel Fry
Iron Man, Robert Downey Jr., Gwyneth Paltrow, Terrence Howard
Avatar, Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver
Star Wars A New Hope, Mark Hamil, Carrie Fisher, Harrison Ford
Air Force One, Harrison Ford, Gary Oldman, Glen Close
Pretty Woman, Richard Gere, Julia Roberts, Jason Alexander
My Best Friend's Wedding, Julia Roberts, dermont Multroney, 
Cameron Diaz
There's Something About Mary, Cameron Diaz, Matt Dillon, Ben 
Stiller
Meet the Parents, Ben Stiller, Robert De Niro, Teri Polo
Top Gun Maverick, Tom Cruse, Jennifer Connelly, Miles Teller
Black Panther: Wakanda Forever, Letitia Wright, Lupita Nyong'o, 
Danai Gurira
Thor: Love and Thunder, Chris Hemsworth, Natalie Portman, 
Christian Bale
Notting Hill, Hugh Grant, Julia Roberts, Richard McCabe
""".strip().split("\n")
```

Then we can iterate the rows looking for rows with only one "entry" and if we find one, append it to the prior row.

```py
rows_fixed = []
prior_row = ""
for row in rows:
    parts = row.split(",")
    if len(parts) == 1:
        prior_row += row
        continue
    if prior_row:
        rows_fixed.append(prior_row)

    prior_row = row

if prior_row:
    rows_fixed.append(prior_row)

rows = rows_fixed
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

That should give you a result like:

```
La La Land, Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone
Blade Runner 2049, Harrison Ford, Ryan Gosling, Ana de Armas
Cruella, Emma Stone, Emma Thompson, Joel Fry
Iron Man, Robert Downey Jr., Gwyneth Paltrow, Terrence Howard
Avatar, Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver
Star Wars A New Hope, Mark Hamil, Carrie Fisher, Harrison Ford
Air Force One, Harrison Ford, Gary Oldman, Glen Close
Pretty Woman, Richard Gere, Julia Roberts, Jason Alexander
My Best Friend's Wedding, Julia Roberts, dermont Multroney, Cameron Diaz
There's Something About Mary, Cameron Diaz, Matt Dillon, Ben Stiller
Meet the Parents, Ben Stiller, Robert De Niro, Teri Polo
Top Gun Maverick, Tom Cruse, Jennifer Connelly, Miles Teller
Black Panther: Wakanda Forever, Letitia Wright, Lupita Nyong'o, Danai Gurira
Thor: Love and Thunder, Chris Hemsworth, Natalie Portman, Christian Bale
Notting Hill, Hugh Grant, Julia Roberts, Richard McCabe
```